# jquery ui tabs issue with tab selection

Tags: css, jquery-ui, tabs

when using jquery tabs with datatables and i add this line:

```
    var selectedTab = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
    $tabs.find('li').eq(selectedTab).removeClass('ui-tabs-selected').end().tabs('select', selectedTab);
```

this line is the only thing that I have found that will hide the tabs that are not initially active and then when a new tab is clicked it hides the old active tab and makes the tab that was clicked active.

however when i add that line the css for the tabs and the datatables goes away.

the tabs are displayed as a bullet list of anchors to the datatables (which act correctly in terms of hiding and displaying when the link is clicked)

if any one has any ideas how to fix this issue it would be much appreciated. thank you so much!